# Validate a group of fields so that form can only be submitted if 0 or 2+ fields have been completed

Tags: 7, forms

In Drupal 7 I need to validate several cck fields so that the node can only be saved if 0 or two or more fields have been completed. So if only one of the fields is completed validation would fail with an error message like 'Please submit two or more years worth of data, or no data at all'.

I know that I can use[Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) and [Field Group Multiple](https://drupal.org/project/field_group_multiple) To set up groups of fields. I can see that [Field Validation](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation) provides basic validation options, including checking that a minimum of 1 of several fields have been completed. But as far as I can see it does not have the capacity to achieve what I need it to do.

Could you please suggest how to go about forcing a user to either complete 2+ fields or none at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this the right way by installing [field validation](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation) with the field validation extras submodule enabled and creating a validator to extend it.

Inside field_validation/field_validation_extras/plugins/validator I created field_validation_zeroortwoplusofseveral_validator.inc with the following code inside it:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Field validation some of several validator.
 *
 */
$plugin = array(
  'label' => t('Require ZERO or two or more of several fields'),
  'description' => t('Forces the user complete zero or two or more several fields.'),
  'handler' => array(
    'class' => 'field_validation_zeroortwoplusofseveral_validator',
  ),
);

class field_validation_zeroortwoplusofseveral_validator extends field_validation_validator {

  /**
   * Validate field. 
   */
  public function validate() {
    $flag = FALSE;
$group_name = $this->rule->settings['data'];

$required_fields = $this->rule->settings['required_fields'];
if (!is_numeric($required_fields) || $required_fields < 0) {
  return TRUE;
}

$field_values = $this->get_field_column_value($this->items, $this->rule->col);
$field_values = count(array_flip($field_values));

if ($field_values >= $required_fields) {
  $flag = TRUE;
}
if ($field_values == 0) {
  $flag = TRUE;
}

if (!$flag) {
  ctools_include('export');
  $other_group_rules = ctools_export_load_object('field_validation_rule', 'conditions', array('entity_type' => $this->rule->entity_type, 'bundle' => $this->rule->bundle, 'validator' => $this->rule->validator));
  foreach ($other_group_rules as $other_group_rule) {
    // Skip when do not have the same group name, rule is disabled, equal to current rule.
    if ($other_group_rule->settings['data'] != $group_name || !empty($other_group_rule->disabled) || $other_group_rule->name == $this->rule->name ) {
      continue;
    }
    $other_items = isset($this->entity->{$other_group_rule->field_name}[$this->langcode]) ? $this->entity->{$other_group_rule->field_name}[$this->langcode] : array();
    $other_field_values = $this->get_field_column_value($other_items, $other_group_rule->col);
    $field_values += count(array_flip($other_field_values));
    if ($field_values >= $required_fields) {
      $flag = TRUE;
      break;
    }
  }
}

    if (!$flag) {
      $this->set_error();
    }
    $break = TRUE;
    return $break;
  }

  /**
   * Provide settings option
   */
  function settings_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $default_settings = $this->get_default_settings($form, $form_state);
    //print debug($default_settings);
    $form['settings']['data'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Group name'),
      '#description' => t("Specify the group name for those fields, it should be the same across those fields. Validation rules with the same group name work together."),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($default_settings['data']) ? $default_settings['data'] : '',
    );
    $form['settings']['required_fields'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Required fields number'),
      '#description' => t("Specify the minimum number of fields that must have a value, it should be the same across fields of the same group. Validation rules with the same group name work together."),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($default_settings['required_fields']) ? $default_settings['required_fields'] : '',
    );
    parent::settings_form($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * helper function to get field values
   */
  function get_field_column_value($items, $column ='value') {
    $field_values = array();
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      if (isset($item[$column]) && $item[$column] !='') {
        $field_values[] = $item[$column];
      }
    }
    return $field_values;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I assume this must be for Drupal 6 since you are describing CCK fields? I would suggest creating a small custom module, and implementing [hook_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!node.php/function/hook_validate/6).

You can then check how many fields have been entered by your user to see if it passes your requirements described above.

If the validation fails you can then display the error to the logged in user with [form_set_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/6)

**EDIT**:

Since you're using Drupal 7, you can use [hook_node_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) within a custom module.

Comment: Thank you AlexK. Apologoes for not being clear - I am using Drupal 7, but learned on 6 and so still think of them as CCK fields even though they are now in core. That is an interesting idea about using hook_validate and form_set_error. I assume that the approach is still ok for D7?

Comment: No problem, I'll edit my answer to be suitable for D7 :)

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is helpful, but actually i found a simpler, if dirtier, method which I'll write up shortly